# Array in array in array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I'm a bit struggling with the associative arrays in associative arrays. Point is that I always have to drill deeper in an array and I just don't get this right.

```
$array['sections']['items'][] = array (
      'ident'         =>  $item->attributes()->ident,
      'type'          =>  $questionType,
      'title'         =>  $item->attributes()->title,
      'objective'     =>  (string) $item->objectives->material->mattext,
      'question'      =>  (string) $item->presentation->material->mattext,
      'possibilities' =>  array (
          // is this even neccesary to tell an empty array will come here??
          //(string) $item->presentation->response_lid->render_choice->flow_label->response_label->attributes()->ident => (string) $item->presentation->response_lid->render_choice->flow_label->response_label->material->mattext
      )
);

foreach ($item->presentation->response_lid->render_choice->children() as $flow_label) {
    $array['sections']['items']['possibilities'][] = array (
        (string) $flow_label->response_label->attributes()->ident => (string) $flow_label->response_label->material->mattext
    );
}
```

So *'possibilities' => array()* contains an array and if I put a value in it like the comment illustrates I get what I need. But an array contains multiple values so I am trying to put multiple values on the position  *$array['sections']['items']['possibilities'][]*

But this outputs that the values are stores on a different level.

```
...
[items] => Array
   (
      [0] => Array
         (
            [ident] => SimpleXMLElement Object
               (
                  [0] => QTIEDIT:SCQ:1000015312
               )
            [type] => SCQ
            ...
            [possibilities] => Array
               (
               )
         )

      [possibilities] => Array
         (
            [0] => Array
               (
                  [1000015317] => 500 bytes
               )
            [1] => Array 
               ...
```

What am trying to accomplish is with my foreach code above is the first [possibilities] => Array is containing the information of the second. And of course that the second will disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$array['sections']['items']` is an array of items, so you need to specify which item to add the possibilities to:

```
$array['sections']['items'][$i]['possibilities'][]
```

Where $i is a counter in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are appending the Arrays to [items]. But you want to append them to a child element of [items]:

You do:

```
$array['sections']['items']['possibilities'][] = ...
```

But it should be something like:

```
$array['sections']['items'][0]['possibilities'][] = ...
```

Comment: We all have those face palm moments ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I have:

```
array[{IsChecked: true, SEC: 0, STP: 0},
      {IsChecked: ture ,SEC: 0, STP: 1},
      {IsChecked: false, SEC: 1 ,STP: 0}]
```

How to get each SEC where IsCheked value is true?

Answer (score 0):

`$array['sections']['items']` is an array of items, and as per the way you populate the `possibilities` key, each item will have it's own `possibilities`. So, to access the `possibilities` of the item that is being looped over, you need to specify which one from `$array['sections']['items']` by passing the index as explained in the first answer.
**OR**
To make things simpler, you can try

1. Save the item array (RHS of the first `=`) to a separate variable instead of defining and appending to the main array at the same time.
2. Set the possibilities of that variable.
3. Append that variable to the main `$array['sections']['items']`